# curl not working in localhost linux fedora

Tags: php, curl, localhost

Hi i tried the google search api using curl from my local linux fedora machine, but i am not getting any result . The curl in not working in my local machine i suppose. how to make it work. here is my code.

```
<?php         
echo $url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/video?=1.0&q=iphone&userip=1xx.1xx.5x.6x";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,"www.example.com"); 
$body = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($body);
print_r($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Install php5-curl and Enable cURL extension from php.ini.

1. Linux command  for install cURL

   ```
   apt-get install curl libcurl3 php5-curl
   ```
2. search extension=curl.so in php.ini and remove ';'.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the curl_error() function to check for any error message.

You  can try to add this values too :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```